# async doesn't return data in callback after mongoose upgrade

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose, bluebird

In my project I use `async` for asynchronous queries to the database and I have this piece of code:

```
async.auto({
        one: function(callback){
            getFriendsIds(userId, callback)
        },
        two: ['one', function(callback, results){
            getFriendsDetails(results.one, callback);
        }],
        final: ['one', 'two', function(callback, results) {
            res.status(200).send(results.two);
            return;
        }],
    }, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            sendError(res, err);
            return;
        }
    });
```

The method returning friends' ids looks like this:

```
function getFriendsIds(userId, callback) {
    var query = User.findOne({_id: userId});

    query.exec(function(err, user) {
        if(err) {
            callback(err);
            return;
        }

        return callback(null, user.friendsIds);
    });
}
```

It worked perfectly. The function returned friends' ids and I used them in the "two" block of async call.

After upgrading `mongoose` from `4.3.7` to `4.7.8` it stopped working. I started getting `Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead` warning and ids were not returned in the callback anymore.

So I added `bluebird` package to the project and plugged it in to the `mongoose`. Now the warning is gone, but ids are still not returned in the callback.

I also upgraded `async` to the newest version, but it didn't help either.

Is there anything more I should do in order to make this work?

Comment: did you tried promises like this, mongoose.promise = require('bluebired),  mongoose.Promise = global.Promise, mongoose.Promise = require('q').Promise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of using promises is to not use callbacks, and you're still using callbacks in your code.

Assuming you require bluebird like

`mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');`

your function should now instead look like this:

```
function getFriendsIds(userId) {
    //This will now be a bluebird promise
    //that you can return
    return User.findOne({_id: userId}).exec()
        .then(function(user){
            //return the friendIds (this is wrapped in a promise and resolved)
            return user.friendsIds;
        });
}
```

The returning value of the function will be an array of the `user.friendsIds`. Taking advantage of the chaining possibilities of promises, you can write a function that fetches the details of each friend, and return that as an array of `friendDetails`.

```
function getFriendsDetails(friendIds) {
    //For each friendId in friendIds, get the details from another function
    //(Promise = require("bluebird") as well)
    return Promise.map(friendIds, function(friendId) {
        //You'll have to define the getDetailsOfFriend function
        return getDetailsOfFriend(friendId);
    });
}
```

and simply call it like

```
getFriendsIds(123)
    .then(getFriendsDetails) //the resolved value from previous function will be passed as argument
    .then(function(friendDetails) {
        //friendDetails is an array of the details of each friend of the user with id 123
    })
    .catch(function(error){
       //Handle errors
    });
```

---

If you want to write less code, you can let bluebird *promisify* the mongoose functions like this

```
Promise.promisify(User.findOne)(123)
    .then(function(user){
        return user.friendsIds;
    })
    .then(getFriendsDetails)
    .then(function(friendDetails) {
        //Return or do something with the details
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        //Handle error
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, it's almost working for me :) The one last thing I need to do is to pass a second argument to the getFriendsDetails function, instead of ``getFriendsDetails(ids)`` it should be ``getFriendsDetails(ids, myId)``. How can I do it? I tried with ``.bind(null, myId)``, but it didn't work.

Comment: If you want to pass more than the previously resolved value to the next `.then()` function, just write it as `.then(function(userIds) { return getFriendsDetails(userIds, myId); })`, assuming that `myId` is defined earlier. I wont update the answer as it differs a bit too much from the original question.